# Python Pandas - series indexing notation

Tags: python, pandas

This is probably an easy question but did not come across explanation in Pandas
beginner tutorials.

When you create a series:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series(range(1,11))
```

you get an output which shows index going from 0 to 9.
`x[0] = 1`, `x[9] = 10`

`x.index` --> `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')`

so why when you input `x[0:9]`, does it leave out the last value 10. Can anyone
explain the inconsistency in indexing notation?

I'm aware of other indexing methods such as x.iloc, etc, but haven't seen a
solid explanation tying them together.

```
>>> x[0:9]
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
6    7
7    8
8    9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: "so why when you input x[0:10], does it leave out the last value 10."  Could you post a transcript showing that happens?  I don't think it should.

Comment: Sorry can't reproduce on pandas 0.15.2 works as expected

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't leave out the last value.

Comment: sorry, made edit. Meant to say x[0:9]. Posted the output I'm getting. For reference, I'm using iPython QT console (Python v 2.7).

Answer (score 2):

Python indexing is inclusive of the first number and exclusive of the last number.  There's no inconsistency here, its just how python indexing works.

x[0:9] means 0-8 inclusive i.e. x[0:9]=x[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], so it outputs the values 1-9 inclusive i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

I guess the only strange part is where a single value is used. x[9] outputs 10, but you should just think of this as being inclusive of the first index value.

Try repopulating your series with letters rather than numbers and it will seem much less confusing and will make sense with the rest of python indexing:

[image: input and output from letter based pandas series and indexing]

Comment: thanks for the response. That makes sense, although I still find it counter intuitive! will have to get used to that.

Comment: Glad this helps.  Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied :-)

Answer (score 1):

In brief, selecting one value in the Series works differently from selecting many values (aka slicing). Slicing automatically ignores the last index, whereas selecting one value simply cannot do that (the only index is the first and the last index, if you ignore it, you have no index to work with).